# How to plot multiple lines stacked individually in one graph? (Y-trace offset)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, facet, facet-wrap

I have a CSV file with individual labels on the 15 first column, followed by 6000 rows of values associated with each label. I'd like to plot them all together in one graph, formatted with the same y-axis limits and stacked in the one graph. Not overlapping each other, just stacked on top of each other with the respective label on the side of each trace. Is there a way to accomplish this in either R (maybe using facets or plotly)?

data would look like this for example:

```
L1 4 5 7 6 ...... 5.5 
L2 9 5 8 .6 ...... 3
L3 2 1 8 4.2 ...... 6.2
.
.
.
L15 2 3.2 4 2 ..... 4.2
```

L1 through L15 represent the label for each row. I would want to plot out the values that come after the label on the y-axis, and just have the x-axis be number of values (6000) since that represents time (in frames).

Comment: What are you trying to plot in your line graph? Also, what do those values after "L1, L2, L3..." represent: how many columns go across and what do the numbers going across represent?  It's going to be difficult to propose a way to help you without more information.  If you cannot post all your dataset, can you give us the output of a portion (like the first 5 rows, lets say) via `dput`?  Post the output of `dput(head(your.data.frame, 5))` for example.  Also, give an example of the ggplot code and output that you want to see... maybe even for just one of your labels.

Comment: You seem to be describing a strip chart which you can create using the `stripchart()` function. See the manual page for details. Do you want the "number of values (6000)" on each line or 6000 separate values on each line?